# How to fetch profileName and permssionSets assigned to the all active users based on profile name

Tags: apex, soql, query, soql-injection

Requirement:I need to fetch a data with username with profileName and permission Sets assigned to users based on profile.

Here I have written a Query for fetching user.
Below is the query

```
select  user.FirstName, user.profile.name FROM user where user.IsActive=true and  user.profile.name='Standard User'
```

Can anyone please modify the query so i will get all the users permission set assigned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query on permission sets held by a user](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31655/query-on-permission-sets-held-by-a-user)

Comment: Thanks Rohit,But is this possible in a single query to find profile name and Permission sets  assigned to User based on Profile Name

Comment: Please help me out here to solve this problem as this is very critical.   Basically i need to fetch active users profiles and Permission sets(but its very difficult to query for each user ,So here i am trying to fetch by profile name ).I am getting user names based on profile ,but how i can get for each users permission sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me know if this works for you : SELECT count() FROM PermissionSetAssignment p WHERE p.PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = false AND p.Assignee.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'

Please mark this as best answer if it resolves your query.

Answer (score 6):

Try the SOQL code below :

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Assignee.Name, p.Assignee.Profile.Name, p.PermissionSet.Label
FROM PermissionSetAssignment p
WHERE p.PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = false AND p.Assignee.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
ORDER BY p.AssigneeId, p.PermissionSetId
```

Comment: Thanks very much .Query is Working as expected..Kudos to you

Comment: HI Vipul,  Is this possible to get count for each profile and for each permission set how many users are there (count).

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you :  SELECT count()
FROM PermissionSetAssignment p
WHERE p.PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = false AND p.Assignee.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'