# SOQL Query - Field Permissions by Permission Set for a Custom Object

Tags: soql, custom-object, permissions, fields

I am trying to run a query to determine which Permission sets grant Field access to my Custom Object `KimbleOne__ActivityTimePattern__c`.  I ran the query below to determine which Permission Sets grant Object level access:

```
Select name from PermissionSet where id IN
(select ParentId from ObjectPermissions WHERE SobjectType='KimbleOne__ActivityTimePattern__c' AND PermissionsEdit=true)
AND IsOwnedbyprofile=false
```

One of the results in the above Query was the custom Permissions set *Edit Delivery Activity Period Rate Band*.

When I run the query below to output Field Permission it yields 0 results.

```
Select Field, SobjectType ,ParentId, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsRead 
From FieldPermissions
WHERE SobjectType='KimbleOne__ActivityTimePattern__c'
Order by field, ParentID, SobjectType ASC
```

This is clearly incorrect as when I view the *Edit Delivery Activity Period Rate Band* permssion Set I can see there are several field permissions under the *Activity Time Pattern* Object

[image: Permission Set detail]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/129801/2212) to see if it doesn't help point you in the right direction to resolve your issue.

Comment: @crmprogdev  - thanks for the quick response!   
The user In question is has 152 Permission sets assigned.  I am primarily interested in Field Permissions so I ran the query below.  This only returned 2 Permissions sets.`SELECT Name,
            (SELECT
                    SObjectType,
                    Field,
                    PermissionsRead,
                    PermissionsEdit
                FROM FieldPerms) 
FROM PermissionSet WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT PermissionSetId
            FROM PermissionSetAssignment
            WHERE AssigneeId = '00558000000Rq55'`